# Angular 2 and WebPack: how to reduce the size of the bundle?

Tags: angular, webpack

I tried a few Angular 2 seed projects that use WebPack. When I build the bundle to release it to Prod, I end up with a file of about 3MB.

How could I reduce the size of this file?

One such project is: https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed

Comment: Are you using the tree shaking and aot options? `npm run build.prod.rollup.aot` ? Also you can ignore the size of .map files.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the project you provided use webpack.

If you are just looking for a seed project, you can checkout [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli). `ng build --target=production` do a pretty good production build.

If you are using webpack now, one thing you can check is the `devtool` in your webpack config, make sure it is not `eval`. Use `source-map` may help.

Answer (score 1):

Minimum size with Webpack is around 800kb for empty application, i suspect you are doing something wrong. Source maps are optional.

Answer (score 0):

There are some important things how to reduce your bundle size:

1. Try to use lazyLoading. This will be great to reduce the main bundle size, and it will split as a chunk files.
   Refer to this document : https://angular.io/guide/router
2. remove the unwanted Packages.
   **Example**:
   if you want to use the boostrap `modal` module, you can import it like this `import {modalModule} from ngx-boostrap/modal`